# Select dropdown filter displaying more than one same records in data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using a data table with a select dropdown filter. It's working perfectly.
My issue is in the select dropdown, I am getting the same record more than one that also correct because I have records like that in the table. So I have to display only a single option.

For example, I have a table and records are like

```
id    | name  | game      | ground 
1     | lkjh  | Cricket   | ground1
2     | poiu  | Baseball  | ground2
3     | qwee  | Cricket   | ground3
4     | adsd  | badminton | ground4
5     | poiu  | badminton | ground5
```

So I am getting the dropdown like. (It's just an example)

```
<select>
<option>Cricket</option>
<option>Baseball</option>
<option>Cricket</option>
<option>badminton</option>
<option>badminton</option>
</select>
```

I need like this

```
<select>
<option>Cricket</option>
<option>Baseball</option>
<option>badminton</option>
</select>
```

Would you help me out on this issue? I am using below script and reference link is https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#paymentList').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns("2").every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select name="select_filter_action"><option value="">All</option></select>')
          .appendTo($("#select_filter_action").empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          //console.log(d);
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating selection options for filter, you need to select only unique values. You can check below code for this:

```
var selectOptionsCollections = [];
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(d, selectOptionsCollections) === -1) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        selectOptionsCollections.push(d);                        
    } 
} );
```

This code is for datatable alteration which you have shared on above link. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Can you help me out in this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360592/search-and-pagination-not-working-while-using-server-side